# Can we replace Springframework annotations (@CacheConfig, @Cacheable, @CachePut) in the XMl file?

Tags: spring, spring-cache, spring-framework-beans

I am implementing a module with Spring Cache mechanism. The module is generic and can cache different type of entities. So I don't want to change the Java code and want the user to configure the applicationcontext.xml file accordingly. He can put the name of the different types of entities within the applicationcontext.xml and the code should work. For e.g. -

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<cache:annotation-driven cache-manager="cacheManager"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.nokia.oss.sure.adapter"/>

<bean id="NetworkEntityService" class="com.nokia.oss.sure.adapter.cache.NetworkEntityServiceImpl"/>

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
    <property name="caches">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean" name="NetworkEntity"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

He may change NetworkEntity to ServiceEntity and so on.

So in the Java code I need to mention -

```
@CacheConfig(cacheNames={"NetworkEntity"})
```

Or I can put the same for every method -

```
@CachePut(cacheNames="NetworkEntity", key="#entity.sureName")
public Entity addEntity(Entity entity) {
    return entity;
}
```

But as I stated earlier, I don't want to put the cache name "NetworkEntity" in the Java code, but want to put the same in the applicationcontext.xml file. Is it possible?

Furthermore is it possible to omit all the annotations in the Java file? If I just use `AbstractApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");` is it possible to mention in the applicationContext.xml file what are the methods where I want to apply the @Cacheable annotation for e.g.

I searched a lot, couldn't find it anywhere.

Thanks
Nirmalya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer. We can put the following in the applicationContext.xml -

```
<!-- define caching behavior -->
    <cache:advice id="cacheAdviceInterface" cache-manager="cacheManager">
        <cache:caching cache="NetworkEntity">
            <cache:cacheable method="getEntity"/>
            <cache:cache-put method="putEntity"/>
        </cache:caching>
    </cache:advice>
```

In that case we don't need to put the @CacheConfig, @CachePut etc annotations within the Java file.